# Android is using the same instance activity after destroyed

Tags: android

- I'm using a `LoginActivity` to Log in with [Smart Lock](https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/).
- I start the `LoginActivity` as `startActivityForResult`. I'm interested in if Smart Lock has a credential, and return `RESULT_OK` if everything is ok. Then I call `finish()`:

  ```
  loginActivityViewPresenter.setResult(RESULT_OK)
  loginActivityViewPresenter.finish()
  ```

After this, `onDestroy()` is called. Let's imagine this is the instance `@7161`.

Then I log out, and I want to log in again, and the same instance is on the top `@7161`.

Functions like `isDestroyed()` or `isFinishing()` are always true.

Why?

Comment: I don't know why, but what flags do you use to start the activity? What happens if you use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK ?

Comment: Nope, same instance `@7337` this time

Comment: This is interesting. Why does it matter if it uses the same object? Perhaps something is still referencing the activity so that it is being kept in memory instead of GC. Do you know how to take a heap dump?

Comment: It matters because you can't touch views when `Activity` is destroyed. I'm interested in that for long running async tasks. I'm trying for other activities and it seems to work perfectly (it creates new instances)...

Comment: If you are using async task then that activity reference might still be available (the async task is holding a reference to it). Android might be launching that existing reference because it still exists. Can you do a heap dump when you finish the activity and see if it still exists in the heap and if so maybe what is referencing it. You could also try a tool called leak canary.

Comment: I can see `LoginActivity` with Depth 3, Native Size 0, Shallow Size 312, Retained Size 2459, but why does that happen?

Comment: I just got the problem. The Smart Lock is keeping my activity!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the AsyncTasks you are using or some other object are keeping are a reference to your activity and the android framework is using that existing activity when you start it again.

You can determine this by doing a heap dump after finishing the activity and looking at the references to this activity.

You could also use a tool called Leak Canary.

Comment: Indeed, `GoogleApiClient` is keeping my `FragmentActivity`, that was the problem! thanks